# How to count distinct values in SQL union?

Tags: sql, mysql, union

I can select distinct values from two different columns, but do not know how to count them.
My guess is that i should use alias but cant figure out how to write statement correctly.

```
$sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT author FROM comics WHERE author NOT IN 
                ( SELECT email FROM bans ) UNION
                SELECT DISTINCT email FROM users WHERE email NOT IN 
                ( SELECT email FROM bans ) ";
```

Edit1: i know that i can use `mysql_num_rows()` in php, but i think that takes too much processing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could wrap the query in a subquery:

```
select  count(distinct author)
from    (
        SELECT  author
        FROM    comics 
        WHERE   author NOT IN ( SELECT email FROM bans ) 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  email 
        FROM    users 
        WHERE   email NOT IN ( SELECT email FROM bans )
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

There were two `distinct`s in your query, and `union` filters out duplicates.  I removed all three (the non-distinct union is `union all`) and moved the distinctness to the outer query with `count(distinct author)`.

Comment: Then use `select  count(distinct something)` and alias both author and email to something.

Comment: @chx: The uppermost part of the union determines the column names. In this case, the column's name will be `author`

Answer (score 3):

You can always do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT...) x` and just copy that `UNION` into the second `SELECT` (more precisely, it's called an anonymous view).

Comment: I think that i tried to do something similar, but thing is that there are some valus which appear in both tables, so they would get counted twice, and i need to count them only once.